# add and get the average of values inputted by user from dynamic textboxes using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I have 5 textboxes displayed, a user can add more textboxes dynamically. However, I am not able to get the the sum and average of the values inputted by users on those textboxes. Can you please help me. I will really appreciate it.

**Hear is the HTML code:**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Grading System </title>
    </head>
    <script src="addInput.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
        </script>                             
        <body>
        <center> GRADING SYSTEM <br><br>
<form method="POST">

    <div id="dynamicInput">
    Subject number 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]"><br>
    Subject number 2<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]"><br>
    Subject number 3<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]"><br>
    Subject number 4<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]"><br>
    Subject number 5<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">   
    </div>
<input type="button" value="Add a subject" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
<input type="button" name="BtnCompute" onClick="avg('dynamicInput');" value="Compute Average">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Then here's the Javascript code:**

```
var counter = 5;
var limit = 10;
var sum=0;
var average=0;


function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {

          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Subject number " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]' >";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
         counter++


     } 
}
function avg(divName){
sum += document.getElementsByName("myInputs[]")[0].value;
average = sum / counter
alert("Average is " + average);   
return false;
}
```

Comment: Explain more what you are unable to do, what you tried and what you think should work. This site won't write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems with your original function:

```
function avg(divName) {

    // you only look at one <input> element ever time, rather
    // than iterating over the collection returned by
    // 'document.getElementsByName("myInputs[]")'; plus you're using
    // a global value which is (at least potentially) exposed to
    // every other function, which makes it vulnerable to being
    // over-written by other values; also: you're not ensuring that
    // the entered-value is a Number (an <input> returns its value as
    // a String, not a Number):
    sum += document.getElementsByName("myInputs[]")[0].value;

    // here you're working out the average of two global values,
    // both of which could be corrupted by other functions, and
    // neither of which - being global - are guaranteed to be
    // Numbers, since you're not enforcing that anywhere. Also
    // you've exposed yourself to potential browser interference
    // by not ending the line with the (optional) semi-colon:
    average = sum / counter

    // this is personal, but for debugging I'd recommend use of
    // console.log() (but, again, a purely personal reccomendation
    // and not really a 'problem' as such):
    alert("Average is " + average);
    return false;
}
```

My correction of your original function would be:

```
function avg() {

    // rather than passing in an argument explicitly, I've opted
    // to use a custom data-* attribute to contain the id of the
    // relevant <div> (see the HTML below, this simplifies
    // changes somewhat in the future):
    var div = document.getElementById(this.dataset.divname),

    // using Node.querySelectorAll() to retrieve the relevant
    // <input> elements (my inclination would be to further
    // amend the selector to 'input,' but that depends on
    // whether or not you'd have any irrelevant <input>
    // elements contained within the same <div>):
        inputs = div.querySelectorAll('input[type=text][name="myInputs[]"]'),

    // using Function.prototype.call() to apply the
    // Array.prototoype.map() function to the Array-like
    // NodeList returned by document.querySelectorAll(),
    // and returns an Array of (in this case) entered values:
        sum = Array.prototype.map.call(inputs, function (inputNode) {

            // here we convert the existing value of the <input>
            // element-node to a Number (<input> elements return
            // their values as a String) or, if the value can't
            // be converted to a Number, or the <input> has no
            // entered value, we return 0:
            return parseFloat(inputNode.value) || 0;

        // using Array.prototype.reduce() to sum the
        // Array of values returned by Array.prototype.map():
        }).reduce(function (a, b) {

            // here we return the sum of the previous number
            // and the current number:
            return a + b;
        // the 0 here is the initial starting value
        // to which the numbers are added:
        }, 0),

        // ensuring that the counter variable (first
        // argument) is parsed into an integer value
        // (using parseInt(), in base-10 (the second
        // argument):
        average = sum / parseInt(counter, 10);

    console.log("Average is " + average);
    return false;
}

// here we use JavaScript to attach the event-handling function to
// the relevant <input> (I added the 'id' to enable this), and
// this binds the avg() function to handle the 'click' event:
document.getElementById('btnCompute').addEventListener('click', avg);
```

The HTML for the amended `<input>` element:

```
<input id="btnCompute" data-divname="dynamicInput" type="button" name="BtnCompute" value="Compute Average" />
```

```js
var counter = 5;
var limit = 10;

function addInput() {

  // note that I've amended this function also, to
  // use the 'data-divname' attribute to hold the
  // 'id' of the relevant <div>:
  var div = document.getElementById(this.dataset.divname);
  if (counter == limit) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "Subject number " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]' >";
    div.appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++
  }
}

function avg() {
  var div = document.getElementById(this.dataset.divname),
    inputs = div.querySelectorAll('input[type=text][name="myInputs[]"]'),
    sum = Array.prototype.map.call(inputs, function(inputNode) {
      return parseFloat(inputNode.value) || 0;
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0),
    average = sum / parseInt(counter, 10);

  snippet.log("Average is " + average);
  return false;
}

document.getElementById('addNew').addEventListener('click', addInput);
document.getElementById('btnCompute').addEventListener('click', avg);
```

```css
label,
input[type=text] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<!--
     Note that I've also amended your HTML, removing the
     unnecessary <br /> elements, instead using CSS to
     provide line-breaks; and also wrapping the <input>
     elements in <labels>, both to enable the CSS line-
     breaks and to enable clicks on the text to focus
     the associated (nested) <input> element:
-->

<form method="POST" action="#">
  <div id="dynamicInput">
    <label>Subject number 1
      <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" />
    </label>
    <label>Subject number 2
      <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" />
    </label>
    <label>Subject number 3
      <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" />
    </label>
    <label>Subject number 4
      <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" />
    </label>
    <label>Subject number 5
      <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <input id="addNew" data-divname="dynamicInput" type="button" value="Add a subject" />
  <input id="btnCompute" data-divname="dynamicInput" type="button" name="BtnCompute" value="Compute Average" />
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vzftsz3a/), for experimentation/development.

Despite my correction of your function though, I'd probably take an alternative approach:

```
// because I retrieve the number of elements in a couple
// of places, I created a simple function to retrieve
// that number of elements:
function currentlyExisting(selector) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector).length;
}

// rewritten in my own style (though this is irrelevant to the
// the question you asked):
function addNew() {

    // still using the value of the custom 'data-divname'
    // attribute:
    var parent = document.getElementById(this.dataset.divname),

    // rather than creating a HTML string, here I create nodes
    // using document.createElement() and a textNode, using
    // document.createTextNode():
        label = document.createElement('label'),
        input = document.createElement('input'),

     // getting the number of currently-existing <input>
     // elements using the above function, passing the
     // selector as an argument:
        current = currentlyExisting('input[name="myInputs[]"'),
        limit = 10;

    // if the current number of <input> elements is less than
    // the limit:
    if (current < limit) {

        // we set the type of the created <input>:
        input.type = 'text';

        // and the name property:
        input.name = 'myInputs[]';

        // appending a textNode to the created <label> element:
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Subject number ' + (current + 1) + ':' ));

        // appending the created <input> to the created <label>:
        label.appendChild(input);

        // attaching the created <label>, along with its own
        // childNodes, to the parent div (retrieved and cached above):
        parent.appendChild(label);

        // setting the disabled property to true if the updated
        // number of <input> elements is equal to, or greater than,
        // the limit; or to false if the number of <input> elements
        // remains less than the limit (preventing the addition of
        // more <input> elements than that identified by the limit):
        this.disabled = currentlyExisting('input[name="myInputs[]"') >= limit;
    }

    // all functions return a value, whether it's explicitly defined
    // or undefined (as this one will), the return false of your
    // original function can be added here instead if you prefer,
    // but I - personally - feel it's unnecessary, so I left it out.

}

function average() {

    // retrieving the relevant <div> element using the
    // data-divname attribute once again:
    var parent = document.getElementById(this.dataset.divname),

        // retrieving the relevant <input> elements:
        inputs = parent.querySelectorAll('input[name="myInputs[]"]'),

        // creating an Array of the values of the relevant
        // <input> elements, using Function.prototype.call()
        // in order to use Array.prototype.map() on the
        // Array-like NodeList returned by querySelectorAll():
        values = Array.prototype.map.call(inputs, function (input) {

            // returning the value of the current <input>
            // element as a number to the array, using
            // parseFloat() to convert that String to a
            // Number; or returning 0 if the String cannot
            // be parsed as a Number:
            return parseFloat(input.value) || 0;

        // using Array.prototype.reduce() to reduce the Array
        // of numeric values (provided by map()) to a single
        // number, the sum of the values:
        }).reduce(function (a, b) {

            // adding the previous and current values
            // together:
            return a + b;
        // here the 0 is the initial value before the Array
        // 'reduction' takes place:
        }, 0),
        average = sum / inputs.length;

    // adding the values to the appropriate elements on screen
    // for easier visualisation (and in a manner that persists):
    document.getElementById('average').textContent = average;
    document.getElementById('sum').textContent = sum;
    document.getElementById('total').textContent = inputs.length;
}

// adding the click event handlers to the relevant button <input>
// elements using EventTarget.addEventListener():
document.getElementById('addNew').addEventListener('click', addNew);
document.getElementById('btnCompute').addEventListener('click', average);
```

```js
function currentlyExisting(selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector).length;
}

function addNew() {
  var parent = document.getElementById(this.dataset.divname),
    label = document.createElement('label'),
    input = document.createElement('input'),
    current = currentlyExisting('input[name="myInputs[]"'),
    limit = 10;

  if (current < limit) {
    input.type = 'text';
    input.name = 'myInputs[]';

    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Subject number ' + (current + 1) + ':'));
    label.appendChild(input);

    parent.appendChild(label);

    this.disabled = currentlyExisting('input[name="myInputs[]"') >= limit;
  }

}

function average() {
  var parent = document.getElementById('dynamicInput'),
    inputs = parent.querySelectorAll('input[name="myInputs[]"]'),
    sum = Array.prototype.map.call(inputs, function(input) {
      return parseFloat(input.value) || 0;
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0),
    average = sum / inputs.length;

  document.getElementById('average').textContent = average;
  document.getElementById('sum').textContent = sum;
  document.getElementById('total').textContent = inputs.length;
}

document.getElementById('addNew').addEventListener('click', addNew);
document.getElementById('btnCompute').addEventListener('click', average);
```

```css
label,
input[type=text] {
  display: block;
}
#average::before {
  content: 'Average: ';
}
#sum::before {
  content: ', sum: ';
}
#total::before {
  content: ', of: ';
}
#total::after {
  content: ' entries.'
}
#total:empty::before,
#total:empty::after,
#sum:empty::before,
#average:empty::before {
  content: '';
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="results">
  <span id="average"></span>
  <span id="sum"></span>
  <span id="total"></span>
</div>
<form method="POST" action="#">
  <div id="dynamicInput">
    <label>Subject number 1:
      <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" />
    </label>
    <label>Subject number 2:
      <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" />
    </label>
    <label>Subject number 3:
      <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" />
    </label>
    <label>Subject number 4:
      <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" />
    </label>
    <label>Subject number 5:
      <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <input id="addNew" data-divname="dynamicInput" type="button" value="Add a subject" />
  <input id="btnCompute" data-divname="dynamicInput" type="button" name="BtnCompute" value="Compute Average" />
</form>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vzftsz3a/1/), for experimentation/development.

References

- HTML:

  - [Custom `data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
  - [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
  - [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: You have explained everything well. You're so intelligent. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So I think you're missing a few things.

```
sum += document.getElementsByName("myInputs[]")[0].value;
```

this line gets only the first input field value, so you need a loop through all the input fields to get the actual sum

```
for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    sum += parseInt(document.getElementsByName("myInputs[]")[i].value);
```

Next, notice the addition of the `parseInt();` method. This converts the input value (which javascript sees as a string by default) into an integer in which you can perform calculations on.

Hope that helps you, cheers

Comment: Thanks for this! it works but when I keep on pressing the button, the values are still adding.